# Recorrido inorden bst junto con nivel de cada nodo - JAVA

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

Una consigna plantea lo siguiente:

**"Desarrollar un método que permita imprimir por pantalla, de manera
ascendente, el código de cada nodo junto al nivel donde se encuentra dicho
nodo."**

Me da a entender que tengo que hacer un recorrido inorden pero mostrando de forma agregada el nivel de cada nodo retornado.

**Los métodos predefinidos que me dan para resolver esto actualmente son los siguientes:**

---

**RECORRIDO INORDEN**

```
public void imprimirEntreorden(NodoArbol p) {
    if (p != null) {
        imprimirEntreorden(p.getIzquierdo());
        //Visito el nodo
        System.out.println(p.getInfo());
        //Visito el nodo
        imprimirEntreorden(p.getDerecho());
    }
}
```

---

**OBTENER ALTURA NODO**

```
public int obtenerAltura(NodoArbol nodo) {
    int alturaParcial, alturaD = 0, alturaI = 0;
    NodoArbol p = nodo;
    if (p.getIzquierdo() != null) {
        alturaI = obtenerAltura(p.getIzquierdo());
    }
    if (p.getDerecho() != null) {
        alturaD = obtenerAltura(p.getDerecho());
    }
    if (alturaI > alturaD) {
        alturaParcial = alturaI + 1;
    } else {
        alturaParcial = alturaD + 1;
    }
    return alturaParcial;
}


public int obtenerAltura() {
    if (this.raiz == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return obtenerAltura(this.raiz);
    }
}
```

---

**ESTE SIGUIENTE MÉTODO FUE MI MODIFICACIÓN AL MÉTODO INORDEN PARA RESOLVER LA CONSIGNA**

```
public void ImprimirAscNivel(NodoArbol p) {

    int nivelNodo = 0;

    if (p != null) {

      nivelNodo = obtenerAltura(p);

        ImprimirAscNivel(p.getIzquierdo());
        //Visito el nodo
        System.out.println("El valor del nodo es: "+p.getInfo()+" y el nivel es "+nivelNodo);

        //Visito el nodo
        ImprimirAscNivel(p.getDerecho());

    }
}
```

---

**ÁRBOL EN CUESTIÓN:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **El resultado es el siguiente...**

El valor del nodo es: 1 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 3 y el nivel es 2

El valor del nodo es: 7 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 10 y el nivel es 3

El valor del nodo es: 11 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 21 y el nivel es 2

El valor del nodo es: 23 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 32 y el nivel es 4

El valor del nodo es: 33 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 34 y el nivel es 2

El valor del nodo es: 36 y el nivel es 1

El valor del nodo es: 50 y el nivel es 3

El valor del nodo es: 51 y el nivel es 2

El valor del nodo es: 62 y el nivel es 1

---

**Las hojas me las marca como nivel 1, y la raíz como el nivel mas alto, en este caso 4.
No debería ser al revés? Y si ese es el caso, como lo resuelvo?
Desde ya, muchas gracias!**

Comment: No comprendo la pregunta. El cálculo de la altura se corresponde con la lógica; fíjate que cuando estás en una hoja el valor es 1 (no hay hijo a izquierda ni derecha, así que el valor retornado es `0+1`) y cada nodo suma 1 a la altura del subárbol más alto.

Comment: @SJuan76 pide en que altura esta el nodo, no la altura del nodo, son dos cosas distintas que se pueden confundir, por ejemplo en el grafico insertado en la pregunta la altura del nodo 0003 es 2 y esta en el nivel de altura 3

Comment: @FrancoRolando Si le han dado como método predefinido `obtenerAltura`, diría que la intención del profesor es que use esa lógica para encontrar el valor.

Comment: @SJuan76 entonces debes obtener la altura del nodo principal y luego, muy inficientemente ir calculando la altura de cada nodo por donde pases e ir haciendo la resta 
AlturaNodoPrincipal-AlturaNodoInterno = AlturaDondeEstaElNodoInterno;
Porque usando ese metodo solo, te va a quedar el nivel de altura de cada nodo mal, osea los que tienen que es X van a ser Y y los que tienen que ser Y van a ser X.

Answer (score 0):

> public void ImprimirAscNivel(NodoArbol p,int altura) {
>
> ```
> if (p != null) {   
>     alturaSig = altura++;
>     ImprimirAscNivel(p.getIzquierdo(),alturaSig);
>     //Visito el nodo
>     System.out.println("El valor del nodo es: "+p.getInfo()+" y el nivel es +altura);
>     //Visito el nodo
>     ImprimirAscNivel(p.getDerecho(),alturaSig);
> }
> ```

y la invocacion a este metodo seria

ImprimirAscNivel(this.p,0);
ya que el metodo obtener altura no te es de utilidad en este caso, porque calcula la altura de un nodo y no te da su posicion.